# trouble fields_for method in rails for multi-model form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. But I am trying to create a form that contains multiple models. I have read up on it and it seems straight forward, but I am unable to get the fields of the child model to render on the form. As I understand the solution I have to put the following into the models

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  #parent model
  attr_accessible :duns, :ord
  has_many :po_recommits
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :po_recommits
end

class PoRecommit < ActiveRecord::Base
  #child model
  attr_accessible :comment, :detail_reason_code, :pid, :po, :qty, 
  belongs_to :message, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

and put the following into the parent controller to create place holders

```
def new
  @message = Message.new
  5.times { @message.po_recommits.build }
end
```

and finally add the fields_for helper to the view

```
<%= form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :org %><%= f.text_field :org %>

  <% f.fields_for :po_recommits do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.label :po %><%= builder.text_field :po %>
  <% end %>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

This code doesn't throw any errors but does not render the `:po` fields on the form. I assume this is because the block is executing 0 times.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think
    <% f.fields_for :po_recommits do |builder| %> 
should be 
    <%= f.fields_for :po_recommits do |builder| %>